# Drupal 7 commerce meta tags not updating

Tags: 7, commerce, meta-tags

I am working with [commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module in drupal 7.

I have installed [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module. It working as expected for drupal default entities like node, taxonomy etc.

But when I try to add meta tags for commerce products, it fails to save the meta tags alone.

Do I need to do any additional settings?

Also my site is built with multilingual properties.

Comment: Well, traditionally meta tags are used on pages, and since commerce products themselves aren't viewable, why are you adding meta tags to products instead of the node associated with the product?

Comment: Then, why drupal providing metatags fieldset on products add/edit pages? Also we have a metatag settings for commerce products as well. Please advice

Comment: I believe it auto attaches to any entity, and in Drupal 7 everything is an entity (taxonomy terms, users, products, nodes, etc.), so you can technically save meta tags to products, but they wouldn't do anything.